# PHP Symfony FormType EntityCollection into Choices

Tags: php, symfony, collections

I am beginner in PHP and Symfony and I started recently on a project.

We have 2 entities which are related by doctrine Annotation ManyToMany with JoinTable

Example: entity and datatable **Room**, entity and datatable **Person** and datatable **RoomPerson** (entity does not exist and just exist in doctrine annotation JoinTable).

The entity Room has a property Collection of Persons.

With a formType it is rendered in page as a select html element multiple (so we can choose several persons)

FormType with preEvent to fill list of possible persons:

```
$allowedPersons = $this->em->getRepository(Person::class)->findBy(***);
    $form
        ->add('personList', EntityType::class, [
            'class' => Person::class,
            'choices' => $allowedPersons ,

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class' => Room::class,
```

New request is to order the list of Persons.

So I made changes described in some tutorials to change declare the Entity RoomPerson et remove annotations ManyToMany for ManyToOne and OneToMany. I added the property "Order" on RoomPerson.
I Added the methods AddRoomPerson and RemoveRoomPerson to make updates of the list by the mapping of my FormType.

So my entity "Room" now only contains a property Collection of RoomPerson.
But I don't know how to use it in my FormType because I always want to show the list of Persons.

I tried a lot of things without success.

example:

```
$allowedPersons = $this->em->getRepository(Person::class)->findBy(***);
    $form
        ->add('roomPersonList', EntityType::class, [
            'class' => RoomPerson::class,
            'choices' => $allowedPersons ,
            'choice_value' => function(?RoomPerson $roomPerson) {
                return $roomPerson? $roomPerson->getPerson()->getIdPerson() : '';
            },
            'choice_label' => function(?RoomPerson $roomPerson) {
                return $roomPerson? $roomPerson->getPerson()->getName() : '';
            },
```

I get following error:

> Argument 1 passed to App\Form\RoomPersonType::App\Form{closure}() must be an instance of App\Entity\RoomPerson or null, instance of App\Entity\Person given, called in ..\vendor\symfony\form\ChoiceList\ArrayChoiceList.php on line 200"

So please I need help to transform my list of RoomPerson in my formtype and to make an update of this list in page.

Comment: If RoomPerson doesn't exist as an entity, why do you use it in your form like `RoomPerson::class`? If this entity doesn't exist than you also can't use it in an `EntityType` form field. If you need to specify the combination of `Person` and `Room` then you should have 2 seperate `EntityType` inputs, one for room and the other for person. Or make the `RoomPerson` datatable into an explict entity

Comment: i added "RoomPerson" as Entity and add property "Order" on it and changed all annotations to make it work and remove property "PersonList" of "Room" to replace it by "RoomPersonList" and i have the collection of RoomPerson is filled correctly but so it no more a collection of Person and i don't know how to make it match in formtype to bind with my choice of Persons in page

Answer (score 3):

When you are creating a form, the `->add`s will make a reference to different columns you have defined in your `App\Entity`.

So, if you want to add something to your form this way, it has to be represented, again, in `App\Entity`.

Now, what you want to do, AFAIU, is fill a `Room` with people (class `Person`), and keep a list of those in the room (`RoomPerson`), **and also a list of where every person has been** (that's why it is a `ManyToMany`).

If instead you are looking at only where a `Person` has been the last time or at the moment, then it is a `OneToMany` relation, cause a **room would be able to hold a bunch of people but any person would only be able to be at one place at a time (obviously)**.

Now I will simply take for granted you want to achieve the `ManyToMany` case. You should have all the columns needed in both `Room` and `Person`.

Now, `RoomPerson` should simply have a connection of those two and it's own id. You can add more things but for the purpose of this example let's just suppose we just need it to be a simple relating table so... your tables would look like (as an example):

```
                      <-M:N->
Room:     <-M->     RoomPerson     <-N->    Person:
   - id (pk)           - id (pk)                - id (pk)
   - space             - room_id (fk)           - gender
   - style             - person_id (fk)         - room_usage
   - purpose                                    - age
   - etc etc...                                 - etc etc...
```

`M` being M number of posible objects on one side, `N` being N number of posible objects on the other side.

Once you have a DB like this, you can simply create a Form where you pass a Room, with every row you need in it.

**If what you want is to select a `room` and have all the people displayed**, you can, **on the controller-side**, get via queries a list of all the people that have been in each room, send it to the form, **and then, on your template-side**, play with `html` and `js` to dinamically show the correct list in each room.

I would need a more precise description to know exactly what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My problem is that i need to add column ORDER in my jointable. The only way i found is to fill my list created via Controller Side and i created Entity duplicated from Person but without the binding so i can use it in formType

Comment: What is that order for? Can't you just order your list in the client side? Have never heard of someone ordering by adding a column to a table in a db. First of all you can `order` a query, and also `order` on the client side, so why would you want to create a column on your db?